# Slicing a tensor by using indices in Tensorflow

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, slice

Basically I have a 2d array and I want to do this nice numpy-like thing

```
noise_spec[:rows,:cols]
```

in Tensorflow. Here rows and cols are just two integers.

Answer (score 30):

Indeed, TensorFlow now has better support for slicing, so you can use the exact same syntax as NumPy:

```
result = noise_spec[:rows, :cols]
```

Comment: unfortunately `u = U[idx_i,:]` doesn't work on tf 1.8.0. `idx_i` are random indices of rows I wanted to choose. `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` worked.

Answer (score 8):

found out, it's

```
tf.slice(noise_spec, [0,0],[rows, cols])
```