# Splitting tensors in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to split tensor into two parts:

```
ipdb> mean_log_std
<tf.Tensor 'pi/add_5:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>
```

Context: ? is for number of samples and the other dimension is 2. I want to split along the second dimension into two tensorflow of shape 1 along that dimension.

What I tried?(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice)

```
ipdb> tf.slice(mean_log_std,[0,2],[0,1])
<tf.Tensor 'pi/Slice_6:0' shape=(0, 1) dtype=float32>
ipdb> tf.slice(mean_log_std,[0,1],[0,1])
<tf.Tensor 'pi/Slice_7:0' shape=(0, 1) dtype=float32>
ipdb>
```

I would expect the shape to be (?,1) and (?,1) for the above two splits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can *slice* the tensor at the second dimension with:

```
x[:,0:1], x[:,1:2]
```

Or split on the second axis:

```
y, z = tf.split(x, 2, axis=1)
```

---

*Example*:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])

y, z = x[:,0:1], x[:,1:2]

y
#<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_2:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>

z
#<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_3:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y, {x: [[1,2],[3,4]]}))
    print(sess.run(z, {x: [[1,2],[3,4]]}))
#[[1]
# [3]]
#[[2]
# [4]]
```

With split:

```
y, z = tf.split(x, 2, axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y, {x: [[1,2],[3,4]]}))
    print(sess.run(z, {x: [[1,2],[3,4]]}))
#[[1]
# [3]]
#[[2]
# [4]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that what I ended up with a few minutes ago.

Comment: It's mentioned here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42823194/3646408

Comment: Can you explain why x[:,0:1] and not x[:,0].

Comment: `x[:,0:1]` slices the tensor and keeps the original dimensions i.e. 2, while `x[:,0]` extract a single column from the tensor so reduces the dimensions by 1.

Comment: **x[:,0:1] slices the tensor and keeps the original dimensions i.e. 2** : this saved my life