# How to drop last row and last col in a tensor using Keras Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor

Let's say I have a tensor `(None, 2, 56, 56, 256)`. Now I want to have my tensor with shape `(None, 2, 55, 55, 256)` by dropping last col and last row. How can I acheive this using Keras/Tensorflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slicing a tensor by using indices in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715511/slicing-a-tensor-by-using-indices-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tensorflow we can slice tensors using python [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation). SO, given a tensor `X` with shape `(20,2,56,56,256)` say (as you have described but with a batch size of 20), we can easily slice it taking all but the last 'row' in the 2nd and 3rd dimension as follows:

```py
X[:,:,:-1,:-1,:]
```

Note the use of `:-1` to denote "everything before the last 'row'".

Given this know-how about slicing the tensor in tensorflow we just need to adapt it for keras. We could, of course, write a full blown [custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) implementing this (or possibly even find one out there someone else has written - I've not looked but slicing is pretty common so suspect someone has written something somewhere!).

However, for something as simple as this, I'd advocate just using a [Lambda layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/) which we can define as follows:

```py
my_slicing_layer = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:-1,:-1,:], name='slice')
```

And can use in our keras models as normal:

```py
my_model = Sequential([
    Activation('relu', input_shape=(2,56,56,256)),
    my_slicing_layer
])
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that we can treat a tensor in Tensorflow like usual array. Thanks !